# How to turn off autocomplete in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, safari

I have developed a website, in every page there is a search input filed. By typing up its shows the suggestions which match from the searched string. In the chrome browser, when i was typing anything then my html suggestion list was coming but an another chrome's suggestion list was overwriting that suggestion which was coming from the server. So I just added **autocomplete="off"** in the html part it resolved. But now the problem still exists in Macbook's Safari browser. In this it is also showing my suggestions but as an overlay an another suggestion list is coming of all my contact list which is synchronized with my logged in account. How to avoid this? This is not happening in any other website page. It is only with my website. Please help me.

Comment: have you tried to delete your cache? - if you have visited your site previously before you added the autocomplete off it could be the case of the errror

Comment: Remove from data

Comment: there was no chance of cache. I was accessing my website first time with that MacBook

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers autocomplete=off is ignored for several reasons. Edge for example ignore it "to provide increased user value".

Maybe you can hide it in Safari with CSS:

```
.put_your_class_here::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```